# Генерировать числа в заданном диапазоне с удаленным числом

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, случайные-числа

Переменную `number` нужно заполнять псевдослучайными целыми числами в диапазоне `[0,6]`, исключая из этого диапазона определенное число - `exclude_number`.
Есть такой вариант : если `number == exclude_number`, тогда функция `rand()` вызывается еще раз.
Какие у вас есть идеи по поводу этой задачи?

Comment: Вам так и не ответили на вопрос о "вызывать еще раз", так что вставлю свои 5 копеек. Это не лучший метод, так как могут измениться статистические характеристики генерируемых случайных чисел.

Comment: Если пишите на C++, то лучше использовать `<random>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду целые числа - без вопросов.

Генерируем случайные числа от 0 до 5, но просто если число оказывается тем, которое нужно исключить - говорим, что это число 6 :)

Если нужно исключить поддиапазон чисел - точно так же уменьшаем на нужный размер исходный диапазон  и просто отображаем числа из исключаемого диапазона на недостающую часть.

Если же это числа действительные - то вероятность по сути нулевая, так что такое (единственное) число можно просто отбросить.

Вот конкретный пример - с удалением 4:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int sum[7] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        int r = rand()%6;
        if (r == 4) r = 6;
        sum[r]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < (sum[i]+5)/10; ++j) cout << '*';
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Вот как это работает и какую гистограмму строит: [ссылка](https://ideone.com/IphHeg).

Comment: Генерировать нужно строго в этом диапазоне

Comment: Ну так у вас и будут числа в этом диапазоне. Понятие "генерировать"-то относится к конечному результату, иначе у вас выходит задача "сделай нечто, чтоб получилось совсем другое". Если надо найти корни квадратного уравнения - вы же не требуете искать их с помощью какой-нибудь теоремы Пифагора? :)

Comment: Извините - не правильно понял Ваш ответ

Comment: А если исключенное число будет 6? Что делать в этом случае?

Comment: Тогда ничего делать не надо - вы просто генерируете числа от 0 до 5, обычная задача :) Если вы имеете в виду, что заранее не знаете, что введет ваш юзер - то если он введет 6, то по условию генерации от 0 до 5 такое число сгенерировано точно не будет - не будет и перемещений. Все будет работать...

Comment: Вот, взгляните - https://ideone.com/66M8NV

Answer (score 4):

Уменьшите диапазон на 1, то есть используйте диапазон `[0,5].` Затем смотрите, если сгенерированное число больше или равняется exclude_number, то увеличьте его на 1.